# Try to remove item for a list created from text file

Tags: python, list

I open two files and read the data from them into two lists

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file:
     data_list1 = [line.strip() for line in file]
with open('file2.txt', 'r') as file:
     data_list2 = [line.strip() for line in file]

for each in list1:
   if each in list2:
      list1.remove(each)
```

After this I iterate over the first list and try to remove elements that also occur in the second list.

```
for each in data_list1:
    print(each)
```

And I got repeated results from the second list.

Comment: Look into [sets](https://realpython.com/python-sets/).

Comment: `remove` will only remove the first occurrence of the element.

Comment: the element is only one is not repeated in the first list

Comment: Don't remove elements from the list while iterating over it. That's a source of a lot of possible problems.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), instead of loops with `remove()`:

```
lst1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
lst2 = [2, 3]

lst1 = [x for x in lst1 if x not in lst2]
print(lst1)
# [1, 4]
```

Using `remove()` while iterating on the same list **forward** messes up the indexing. If you really want to delete elements from the list while iterating, then a good solution would be to iterate on the index of the list in **reverse** (starting from the end of the list), and use [`list.pop`](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```
for i in reversed(range(len(lst1))):
    if lst1[i] in lst2:
        lst1.pop(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should never try to remove an item from the list you are iterating on. Here a possible way is to filter out elements from the first list when you read the second file:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file:
     data_list1 = [line.strip() for line in file]
with open('file2.txt', 'r') as file:
     data_list2 = list(filter(lambda x: x not in data_list1, line.strip() for line in file))
```

But if the lists are large, is could be more efficient to build a set from the first list because searching in a set is much faster that searching in a list:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file:
     data_list1 = [line.strip() for line in file]
data_set1 = set(data_list1)
with open('file2.txt', 'r') as file:
     data_list2 = list(filter(lambda x: x not in data_set1, line.strip() for line in file))
```